# The function of the button is correct, but the unit test reports an error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I can use the button normally on the page:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <span id='count'>{{count}}</span>
        <button @click="increment">+</button>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                count: 10,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            increment() {
                this.count++;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But my unit test is not detecting the button's effect. Is it because I made a mistake in unit test, and then click it to report an error?

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

import Counter from '@/components/Counter';

describe('test::::', () => {
    it('test1:::', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Counter);
        expect(wrapper.find('#count').text()).to.be.equal('10');
        wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');
        expect(wrapper.find('#count').text()).to.be.equal('11');
    });
});
```

Error message:

> `AssertionError: expected '10' to equal '11'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the assertion occurs before the `click` handler's changes take effect.

The [`trigger()`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/trigger.html) method returns a `Promise` that resolves when the component has updated, so you could make the test callback `async`, and then `await` the `trigger()` call:

```js
it('test1:::', async () => {
   //...
   await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');
   expect(wrapper.find('#count').text()).to.be.equal('11');
});
```